# difference between match and query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between match query and query string query? Say, I have the following queries, do they have the same functionality?

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "_all" : "this is a test"
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "this is a test",

        }
    }
}
```

Considering the fact that using query_string and not indicating any specific field, automatically  _all field will be used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

> Comparison match query to query_string / field
>
> The match family of queries does
>   not go through a "query parsing" process. It does not support field
>   name prefixes, wildcard characters, or other "advanced" features. For
>   this reason, chances of it failing are very small / non existent, and
>   it provides an excellent behavior when it comes to just analyze and
>   run that text as a query behavior (which is usually what a text search
>   box does). Also, the phrase_prefix type can provide a great "as you
>   type" behavior to automatically load search results.